# Появление элемента в хедере при скролле до конца документа

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сори если вопрос глупый. Нужно чтобы кнопка в фиксированном хедере появлялась, когда пользователь доскроллит до конца документа и после этого исчезала при минимальном скролле вверх. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $('.top').addClass('sticky');
   }else {
     $('.top').removeClass('sticky');
   }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.top {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .5rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #ff5252;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .25rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
  display: none;
}

.sticky .btn {
  display: block;
}

main {
  display: block;
  height: 1500px;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="top">
  <a href="#" class="btn">show btn</a>
</header>

<main></main>
<footer>bottom</footer>
```